# Imgur copy&paste on Stack Overflow

Tags: discussion, feature-request

For some time, Stack Overflow has been using Imgur for pasting Images into answers/questions.

I know Imgur accepts images from the clipboard:

[image: Imgur]

Since I always use a capture tool that allows copying to the clipboard, it would be nice to have a paste from clipboard option for Stack Overflow images.

I don't think it would be that hard to implement, but would help me a lot in providing screenshots.

Comment: [Related](/questions/255854/pasting-images-from-clipboard-with-chrome).

Comment: @BenVoigt Feature request seems pretty clear (and useful) to me. And Stack Overflow Meta seems like the appropriate place too...

Comment: @Cerbrus: It's hard to understand why he's asking for something that already exists... therefore I was looking for what "new" behavior he could possibly be requesting (all within "the whole copy-paste an image idea"), with that description.  As you see, I came up with three possibilities, none of which were wholly satisfactory, or likely to be implemented.

Comment: Additionally: can this be extended to the chat's upload feature? I don't know why that uses an older interface (which doesn't allow ctrl + V).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This has been implemented, so you can now paste or drag and drop the images into the editor.

See: [Editor improvements for images and links](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/317576/191655).

[image: paste or drag and drop images into WYSIWYG editor]

Answer (score 67):

It's not obvious, but it's already supported (at least on some browsers).

Hit the image toolbar button or press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>G</kbd>. When the image insertion dialog appears you can paste an image.

[image: Dialog]

Tested to work on:

- Chrome 45 on Windows
- Edge 20

Does not work on:

- IE 11
- Firefox 42
- Safari on iPad
- Chrome on Android

---

I think they should mention in this dialog you can also paste an image. Something along these lines:

> You can also provide a [link from the web](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/306935/imgur-copypaste-on-stackoverflow/306951#306951) or paste an image from the clipboard (Ctrl + V).

Comment: @Jongware IMO the text should only appear on supported browsers. Oh, and for testing you can edit a post without submitting the edit - as long as you get an URL for your image it means it's uploaded. ;-)

Comment: BTW I'd appreciate if someone could test on Firefox/Opera/Safari and edit that into the answer :)

Comment: **I think they should mention in this dialog you can also paste an image** You bet. I have been pasting the time consuming way ever since this part of the interface changed.

Comment: No more wasting time with mspaint for me. This is awesome.

Comment: .. It partially works on my iPad. It is possible to call up a Copy menu on an image, but it lacks a Paste. However, I get an option to call up "Photos" and select an image I saved earlier. Oh well--it's tons better than nothing.

Comment: Doesn't work in chrome for android.

Comment: @CoolGuy thanks for testing, I added it to the answer.

Comment: It should work on FireFox...Why doesn't it? http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/311865/images-in-firefox

Comment: @RuchirBaronia no it should not, balpha (SE developer) explain it [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/242753/152859).