# Using copy-paste to upload images in Firefox?

Tags: support, feature-request, images

I use both Google Chrome and Firefox, but the Stack Overflow website works differently on both websites with images. When directed to this screen:

[image]

In Chrome, we can just use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> to paste the image after using something like a snipping tool or Print Screen.

In Firefox however, we must either save it to our computer, or use something like snag.gy to post our images. Then, we must right click and click "View Image", and finally, in the "Provide a link from the web" dialog, paste the image URL.

That is an awfully long process, so can we have the paste functionality in Firefox also?

Comment: Don't both of those tools save the file locally?  Why can't you just drag it in from where it's saved, or navigate to where it's saved on your machine?  Why do you feel that you need to use the third party image hosting solution when the site has already baked in Imgur?

Comment: I just double checked and dragging and dropping an image works in Firefox.

Comment: @BSMP It does, but I'm talking about `copy and paste` functionality.

Comment: @RuchirBaronia - I mentioned it because Makoto asked why you couldn't just drag it in. I was just confirming that dragging & dropping does work in Firefox.

Comment: Repro'd in IE11, not in edge.  The use case is: "answering a question, I use the snipping tool (win7+) to capture part of my screen.  I click the button to copy the image to the clipboard.  Back in the browser, I click the image button in the post editor. The above image dialog appears.  I type ctrl-v"  Desired behavior (chrome, edge, possibly other browsers)--image is pasted into the dialog. This is most likely to do with HTML5 standards not being supported in the browser, I'd wager. Unsure of in-browser workarounds, but I bet they all suck :/

Answer (score 17):

The dialog is already dynamic to show all the options the browser you're using currently supports, as it runs checks for browser support on all the features it attempts to use. If the browser doesn't support a certain feature, it doesn't show that option.

Firefox does not currently support the paste feature without a focused, editable field which is required to make that work, presumably for security reasons (though I've heard you can manually enable it somehow). So it does not show that option to you when using a Firefox browser. If Firefox ever makes the feature available, the option will automatically appear on its own without need for a code change.

Comment: https://github.com/FineUploader/fine-uploader/issues/774#issuecomment-28239338 has an outline of how you can work around FF from someone who decided it was too much work; https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Projects/Midas/Security_preferences explains how to enable the pasting locally, but that's far too much hassle for almost anyone. (Seriously, user.js? Not even about:config?)

Comment: I never saw any text saying you can press Ctrl+V in that dialog. And I'm [not alone](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/306935/imgur-copypaste-on-stack-overflow/306951?noredirect=1#comment252036_306951). Shouldn't there be something in there?

Comment: @LucasTrzesniewski It *should* explicitly mention it. It used to do that with the old dialog. I had no idea it didn't now because I use Firefox and it's not supported, so I wouldn't see it anyways.

Comment: Do you know how I can "manually enable it" like you stated?

Comment: @RuchirBaronia See Nathan Tuggy's comment above.

Comment: Ctrl-V *does* work in Firefox on http://imgur.com/

Answer (score 3):

This appears to be a [longstanding bug/feature request](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=906420) and as of today (July 2016) is actively being worked on.  Yay!