# Copy & Paste Images for all Browsers

Tags: feature-request

Two month ago, I asked a question about [copy & pasting images on Stack Overflow](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/306935/2441442). 
The result was, it is partially available.

I want to draw some attention back to this topic, since it is not available for:

- IE 11
- Firefox 42
- Safari on iPad
- Chrome on Android

So I request to support this feature on all common browsers (At least for FF and IE).

Comment: These browsers simply don't give us the features to do that. It's not an issue of us not having implemented the code for them.

Comment: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/311865/1228